# Get total number of images in a flip kart main page as every image has same class using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Image details in firebug

```
<img
    class="_3Esdvt _3BdV0_"
    alt="Minimum 40% Off"
    style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px;" 
    src="http://rukmini1.flixcart.com/image/200/200/hand-messenger-bag/b/b/j/dk12hwht-diana-korr-shoulder-bag-becky-bucket-original-imae2u583j8tzay4.jpeg?q=80"
/>
```

Every image has the same class name as mentioned in the above information.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like a simple case of getting a handle of all applicable WebElements and taking a count.

Comment: List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@class='_3Esdvt _3BdV0_']/@src)"));
links.size();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can easily get this by using cssSelector. use the below code:

```
List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(" div.AqZEhb>img[class^='_3Esdvt _3BdV0_']")); 
links.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to get a list of the applicable WebElements and take a count of the returned WebElements:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@class='3Esdvt _3BdV0']"));
links.size();
```